# Retrieving lost draft

Tags: support

It appears that I just lost about eight hours of work on an answer because I left the page for a while and didn't save the draft before I left. The system usually saves drafts, it seems, but not this time.

Is there any way to retrieve the draft, or is it gone forever?

Comment: I have learnt from the Circuit Thingy Plugin that saving to a text file often when working on a complex answer is key (It frubbledeefies up my answers more often than not when working on 4 schematics in one answer). I don't think, if data was not sent to the server yet, that it will be somewhere. But I know not for sure any such thing.

Comment: OOPs...Pilot error. Sorry .

Comment: Alas, the draft system is crude.  One draft question per stack and one draft answer per stack.  If you have a draft answer and you start writing another answer elsewhere, the first draft is quietly discarded.

Comment: There's something weird that happens sometimes where if you click on the SE page (any other page is ok) accidentally when a schematic is being edited the schematic disappears somewhere- it's still hanging about but  can't be accessed. If you open another schematic and repeat the work it hiccups but eventually saves the new schematic. Kinda annoying.